# XCode Not Rebuilding Dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode

I have multiple xcodeprojects that generate libraries. If I make a change to any of the files which are in the libraries it does not compile in the changes.

I have set up target dependencies so that root project depends on the other projects. But making a change does not force the compiler to rebuild them.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: So you're using an Xcode Workspace, right?

Comment: The actual project is a root xcodeproj with each individual extra xcodeproj (libs) dragged in as sub projects. Then the dependencies are added on the root project.

Comment: I have figured this problem out.

Under XCode->Summary->Linked Frameworks And Libraries

I had an umber of libraries that appeared in red. Interestingly it meant they were linked but it also acted like a dependency, i.e. it was not detected they were out of date unless this was correct. Once I removed a library and re-added it. It worked fine and picked up the changes.

Comment: Can whoever closed this as "Not a real question"  re-open it. Its clearly obvious what the question is, XCode isn't rebuilding dependencies and the OP want's to know why. and its an important one. @Asheh, can you , if the boneheaded closure hasn't precluded it, make your solution a proper answer.